# File search and replace with Tie::File

Tags: perl

My search and replace is not working, nor is it throwing any error.

I tried to modify the code and provide the input where it is working. I'm not sure where the error occurs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Tie::File;
use v5.10;
use File::Compare;

my $VAR; $VAR=$ARGV[0];chomp $VAR;

my $nam=qq~file_name~;

my @lines;

our $s1="var1";
our $s2="var2";

if ('$s1' ne '$s2'){
    replace();
}

sub replace {

    chomp $s1;chomp $s2;

    tie @lines, 'Tie::File', "$nam" or die " can't open the file\n";

    foreach ( @lines ) {
        s/$s2/$s1/g; # replacing the strings
    }

    untie @lines;
};
```

Comment: Please, remove the `>` characters. Also, comments in Perl start with a `#`, not `/*`.

Comment: `"$nam"` is the same as `$nam`.

Comment: works dandy for me, after removing this line: `my $VAR; $VAR=$ARGV[0];chomp $VAR;`. Note that there are still other issues per the other commenters.

Comment: @choroba Also `'$s1' ne '$s2'` is _not_ the same as `$s1 ne $s2`. The first is always true.

Comment: @stevieb Not sure what _works dandy_ means (I'm German) but the line seems completely useless. `$VAR` is never refereneced.

Comment: works fine, as-is, after removing the `$VAR` line. (Otherwise, it emits a warning).

Comment: @stevieb Thanks. I thought that but what's the impact of that line after all? Cannot see how it influences the behaviour of the rest of the script.

Comment: it doesn't. it just prevents a long diagnostic message from being printed out. functionally, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @stevieb: The line `my $VAR; $VAR=$ARGV[0];chomp $VAR;` makes no difference at all except that it spews a bunch of diagnostic text. It can be left in place and the program works fine

Comment: yes, I know. I should have been more precise in my original comment. I should have said "it works fine, and after removing X line, prevents it from emitting any diagnostic/warning messages"

Comment: guys i didn't used /*, i only have given here for explaing the lines, i have working prograrm for search and replace but i am trying to grep for a parameter in a file and use it as replacement string for this file...  my $s1="system(\"cd \$folder\;grep $VAR * | awk -F ' ' '{print \$NF}' | head -1\")";
my $s2="system(\"cd $another_folder\;grep $VAR * | awk -F ' ' '{print \$NF}' | head -1\")";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tie::File rarely helps. If you're going to do `for (@lines)` with a tied file, you're going to make things abysmally slow and use way more memory that you would have if you hadn't used Tie::File.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = 'file_name';
$^I = '';   # Like the -i command line option

while (<>) {
   s/var2/var1/g;
   print;
}
```

This is basically the samething as doing

```
perl -i -pe's/var2/var1/g' file_name
```

---

If creating files is not an option, then I'd use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $qfn = 'file_name';

my @lines;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn);
   @lines = <$fh>;
}

{
   open(my $fh, '>', $qfn);
   s/var2/var1/g for @lines;
   print($fh @lines);
}
```

This *way* faster than with Tie::File — 30x faster, IIRC. It also uses *way* less memory than with Tie::File.

Comment: Worth noting that `$^I` is the _inplace-edit extension_. Setting it means editing the file ('file_name' in this case) in-place. It's the same as `perl -p -i -e 's/var2/var1/g;' file_name`.

Comment: normal replace/sed/perl command replace doesn't work for my case,as the directory i am editing doesn't have write permission but the file i am editing has write permission

Comment: hi, thanks dude, i have took your script and modified for my function, but there are 4 occurance of that string but only the 4th occurance is modified, first 3 occurance are not modified, can you help me with it...i have used the same code you have given in "If creating files is not an option, then I'd use the following: "

Comment: Then the first three didn't match for some reason. I haven't seen your pattern or your input, so I can't help you. This sounds like separate question, though, because it has nothing to do with how you read in the data (unless the match you are expecting spans lines).

Comment: thanks Dude, i have added the chomp to my string variable and now all strings are replaced....

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got yourself confused with so many unnecessary `use` statements, calling string constants `var1`, `var2` etc, messing about with `$VAR` which is never used, and calling `chomp` on variables that have no trailing newline

I've rewritten your code so that I could see what it did, and it works fine

It substitutes the value of `$s2` (`var2`) with the value of `$s1` (`var1`) throughout the file. Every `var2` is changed to `var1`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Tie::File;

my $name = 'file_name.txt';

my ($s1, $s2) = qw/ var1 var2 /;

if ( $s1 ne $s2 ) {

    tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $name or die qq{Can't open "$name" the file: $!};

    s/$s2/$s1/g for @lines;
}
```

Comment: actually i have above code working if the sting is inputed as argument but its working where i and using i/p from difference between another file and the currect file using the below command                                                               our $s1="system(\"cd \$DIR/floder\;grep $VAR * | awk -F ' ' '{print \$NF}' | head -1\")"; and the o/p of it is like -var" where - &" is also present with that varible

Comment: #/usr/bin/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Tie::File;


my $nam;
my @lines;
print " enter the file name:\n";
$nam=<STDIN>;chomp $nam;
replace ();

sub replace {
my $s1;
my $s2;

print " ENTER the STRING to be replaced:\n";
$s1 = <STDIN>;
print " ENTER the STRING to  replace:\n";
$s2 = <STDIN>;
chomp $s1;chomp $s2;


tie @lines, 'Tie::File', "$nam" or die " can't open the file\n";
foreach (@lines)
{
s/$s1/$s2/g
}
untie @lines;
};